# Detect Toast Notification from the particular application

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have two application both of them send toast notifications, I want to detect the Toast Notification from the particular application.On search I find`public ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger(string applicationId)`,what would be the application ID during development?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the application ID during development?

Here is the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn913882.aspx) for the parameter:

> The identifier of the app for which you want to create an instance of
>   the ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger class.

More searching on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211415.aspx), here is more info about application identity, which will appear in the package manifest:

```
<Application Id = An ASCII string between 1 and 64 characters in length.
```

> The unique identifier of the application within the package. This
>   value is sometimes referred to as the package-relative app identifier
>   (PRAID). The ID is unique within the package but not globally. There
>   may be another package on the system that uses the same ID. The same
>   ID cannot be used more than once in the same package.

So it means both applications need to exist in the same package. I don't know how is that possible right now and I doubt that it is your case. Most likely, you have multiple packages, one for each app. In this case, you can use [AppServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) to communicate between the two apps.

**Edit**

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/78edc38b-41b9-4fe2-9bbf-20f282ddc25c/uwphow-to-make-2-apps-part-of-the-same-package?forum=wpdevelop) explains about multiple app packages, it is supported for side loading and not the store.

> You can create a multi-app package for side-loading, just not to
>   deploy through the store. When the user installs the package they'll
>   get all of the apps, and the apps will all share the same security
>   context, local data, etc.